# How to write Kelvin equation in a different way

Tags: logarithms

My question is about the Kelvin equation which is as follows:

$$\ln(e/e_s) = \frac{2\cdot\sigma}{n\cdot k\cdot T\cdot r}  $$

Keep in mind that the $e$ in $\ln(e/e_s)$ is not the constant $\mathrm{e}$.

I know that:

$$\frac{e}{e_s} = \mathrm{e}^{(\frac{2\cdot\sigma}{n\cdot k \cdot T \cdot r})}$$

I need to show that this is equal to:

$$\frac{e}{e_s} = 1 + \frac{a}{r}$$

Where $a = \frac{2\cdot \sigma}{n\cdot k\cdot T}$

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You are aware that $\ln(\mathrm{e}^x)=x$, right? (Some people like to write $\mathrm{e}=2.71828…$ with an upright e. When you have other $e$s in the same context, this becomes essential.)

Comment: $\exp(a/r)$ and $1+a/r$ aren't equal, unless $a/r=0$.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting here. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that $e^{a/r} = 1 + a/r$.  But that isn't true.  What is true is that
$$ e^{a/r} = 1 + a/r + \frac{a^2}{2!r^2} + \frac{a^3}{3!r^3} + \cdots$$
So if $a/r$ were small, so that $a^2/r^2$ and all the following terms on the right were very small, then $1+a/r$ would be a good approximation for $e^{a/r}$.

Comment: So it's a taylor expansion, right? 

That would make sense since this questions is asked in the context of a numerical problem set.

Comment: Yes, that's the Taylor expansion for $e^x$ at zero.